# How to isolate pytest tests

Tags: pytest

I'm running a test with class fixture, and how to make `test_b` and `test_c` to be isolated, such that both started with `a_list = ['a']` only.

I know changing the fixture scope to function would achieve what I asked. But the fixture have to be class scoped. Is there some way to tell `test_b` and `test_c` to take a snapshot of `a_lis`t before running?

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def a_list(self):
    return ['a']

def test_b(self,a_list):
    a_list.append('b')
    assert a_list == ['a','b']

def test_c(self,a_list):
    assert a_list == ['a','b']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work on a copy of `a_list` in each test you want to modify it

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def a_list(self):
    return ['a']

def test_b(self, a_list):
    a_list = a_list[:]
    a_list.append('b')
    assert a_list == ['a', 'b']

def test_c(self, a_list):
    assert a_list == ['a', 'b']
```

Output

```
PASSED                                     [ 50%]
FAILED                                     [100%]

example_test.py:31 (Test.test_c)
['a'] != ['a', 'b']

Expected :['a', 'b']
Actual   :['a']
<Click to see difference>

self = <example_test.Test object at 0x0000011696077A90>, a_list = ['a']

    def test_c(self, a_list):
>       assert a_list == ['a', 'b']
E       AssertionError: assert ['a'] == ['a', 'b']

example_test.py:35: AssertionError
```

Comment: How about deployed contract? like I deployed one contract in a class-scope fixture, and test several function on that contract, is there a way to make a snapshot of the state of the contract before each test?

Comment: @LiuzhouZhuo I'm not sure what you mean by *deployed contract*, but you can use `deepcopy` to create a local copy.